# How to programmatically login then redirect with Laravel 5.5?

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, authentication

I am using Laravel 5.5 and PHP 7.1
I am using the standard built-in Auth and middleware, I have not customized anything.

I am wanting to create a route in the api.php routes file that would be something like this:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'mobile'), function () {
      Route::get('requestaccess', ['uses' => 'MobileController@RequestAccess']);
});
```

Then in my MobileController I would have this code:

```
public function RequestAccess() {
    try {
        $input = request()->all();
        $token = $input['token'];
        //$page = $input['page'];

        $user = User::where('mobile_access_token', $token)->first();
        if (!$user)
            return view('public.error', ['errorCode' => 901]);

        if ($user->mobile_access_expires < Carbon::now())
            return view('public.error', ['errorCode' => 902]);

         // I tried with and without the second param (true)
        if (!Auth::loginUsingId($user->id, true))
            return view('public.error', ['errorCode' => 903]);

        // My code makes it to here just fine which means the token
        // was valid and I 
        // successfully logged in.
        // Now I want to send them to a page where the user
        // can browse and remain logged in. 

        // I tried the following line but it does not work
        // It just immediately redirects me to the login page
        return redirect(url('dashboard'));

        // The following line works but if user clicks a link
        // to go to any other page it redirects them to the login page 
        return view('console.dashboard.dashboard');

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return view('public.error', ['errorCode' => 900, 'errorMessage' => $e->getMessage()]);
    }
}
```

and in the web.php route file I have the following:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
    Route::get('dashboard', ['uses' => 'DashboardController@getDashboard']);
});
```

and of course for testing I am typing something like this in my browser:

```
example.com/api/mobile/requestaccess?token=abc
```

Everything is all in one domain I am just wanting to log the user in and have them stay logged in while browsing the site.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API route doesn't have `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class` this middleware, meaning it doesn't have any access to `session` so you cannot maintain session state i.e. logged in state. The purpose of `api` route is to have a stateless transmission.

Comment: So are you suggesting I move the requestaccess route to the web.php route file and that would fix it? If not what are you suggesting I do to fix it?

Comment: Yes, that would allow you to achieve what you want.

Comment: You may want to check [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) in that case.

Answer (score 7):

You can login user by using `Auth::login()` like this

```
public function RequestAccess() {
    try {
        $input = request()->all();
        $token = $input['token'];
        $user = User::where('mobile_access_token', $token)->first();

        if (!$user){
             return view('public.error', ['errorCode' => 901, 'errorMessage' => 'Could not find user']);
        }

        Auth::login($user);

        redirect()->('dashboard');
    }catch(\Exception $e){
        return view('public.error', ['errorCode' => 900, 'errorMessage' => $e->getMessage()]);
    }
}
```

**Note:** You have written that your route is in api and in controller you are rendering view, be sure this code will work for `web` guard that has `StartSession` middleware. If you are looking for api authentication then you can look [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport)

check **Other Authentication Methods** section in 
 https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication#authenticating-users